# Transfer file over ICMP

Tags: networking, icmp

I'm studying about Networking . I'm want to transfer file over ICMP protocol then capture networking traffic by wireshark to decode raw data . But I dont know how to transfer file by ICMP protocol. So my question is how can I transfer file by ICMP between host.
Thanks a lot .

Comment: You can't, unless you abuse one of the sub-protocols of ICMP. You should probably be looking at UDP.

Comment: Seems you are newbie to networking, read something about TCP/UDP first. Actually, there is indeed a way called  ICMP tunnels to transfer file over ICMP, but I don't think you mean that.

Answer (score 5):

If you insist on sending data using ICMP (which is reasonable in some use-cases) I suggest you read [this article](http://www.unixist.com/security/data-transfer-over-icmp/index.html) and [that one](http://www.top-hat-sec.com/r4v3ns-blog/sending-files-through-icmp-ping-packets). The first one also contains proof-of-concept C-code for client and server that use ICMP to transfer data. You can find another example [written in C++ here](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/IcmpFileTransfer).

The idea behind this method is using the data (payload) section of ICMP Echo (ping) requests and responses for transferring data (or files in this case). Most devices reply to ICMP Echo (ping) requests so it's a way to transfer files when other protocols (such as ssh, smb, ftp, etc.) are blocked.

Comment: First two links are dead, but props for not dismissing OP

Comment: I dislike that SHAHS said "technically impossible"--It's not even virtually impossible. Even if you couldn't send data payloads (which we have proof of concepts for), you could still signal data transmission just by sending a packet itself. A ping can be a signifier of data itself with no modifications. "If I receive a ping at 12:01, myBool = 1;" That doesn't mean it's easy, but "technically impossible" is categorically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, a solution would be to craft a packet with python/scapy like

```
from scapy.all import *
pkt = IP(dst="1.2.3.4",src="5.6.7.8") / ICMP(type=8) / (b"This is a s3cr3t string") )
send( pkt )
```

To send a file you could split it up into several chunks so that every chunk fits into the packet, encode each chunk in base64, and decode/reassemble it on the receiving side.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that ANY protocol can be used to send data... as long as you can manipulate at least one bit (or "flag") it is then possible to send data in a stream of 1's or 0's. Morse code. HOWEVER, you'd have a difficult time with packet drops and/or pings arriving in the wrong order due to route path changes. Possible? Yes. Reliable? nope.

Answer (score -2):

If you study about [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) layers, you will find that ICMP is a Internet layer protocol and its purpose is to:

> The Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) is a supporting protocol in the Internet protocol suite. It is used by network devices, like routers, to send error messages and operational information.

So ICMP is not a data transfer protocol like HTTP or FTP etc. Technically it is not possible in any case to use ICMP as data transfer protocol, Unless you change structure and all coding of ICMP and then it will no longer be ICMP.

Comment: then what the heck is [this](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/IcmpFileTransfer)